# bounce after submitting.

Tags: javascript

I finally got the bounce working after the effect, but for some reason, it won't close the facebox after submitting. It closed after submission before, but what is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../_lib/forms/comment_ajax.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>',
    data: { form_name: name, form_comment: comment },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#new_comment').append(data);

        $(document).trigger('close.facebox');

        $('#new_comment').effect("bounce", { direction:'down', times:5 }, 300);    

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 2000, "easeOutElastic");
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the full code. I got it working now. I was including this : <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script> and i think it was classhing with my current core.js file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am just asking why 2 people voted to close this question.

Comment: Too localized means that your question is specific for your current application and not relevant to other people. So others won't really benefit from the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
$(document).trigger('close.facebox');
```

Try this:

```
$.facebox.close();
```